# Skip serialization of fields based on their value

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there any way to selectively skip serialization of fields whose value is equal to a certain known value? AFAIK, DefaultContractResolver isn't enough to achieve this as it doesn't allow to get the field's value.

Comment: You could use the `ShouldSerializeXXX()` pattern.  See e.g. [How to use `ShouldSerialize[MemberName]()` method for a property of type Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19698844/3744182).  Or you could use `DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46767921/3744182) for a single property and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62676615/3744182) for use in settings.  Do those answer your question?  If not, could you [edit] your question to provide more details, ideally a [mcve]?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62699016/10263) shows how to do it with a custom ContractResolver.